# Make javascript if statement display html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted an if statement to show an image or html code depending on the webpage. I got this far and the html table doesn't appear at all (appears blank):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var url = document.location.pathname;

if( document.location.pathname == '/tagged/photos' ){
document.innerHTML('<table><tr> hello </tr> </table>');
}

if( document.location.pathname == '/tagged/news' ){
document.write("<b>This is my news page</b>");
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Also, I don't see any jquery here :)

Comment: No it isn;t working, it doesn't appear at all

Comment: Sorry i'm very new to computer code :(

Comment: Are you following a tutorial from the '90s? Putting scripts in comments isn't necessary, and `document.write` isn't used any more. Also, `innerHtml` is a property, not a method.

Comment: Start by log the pathname "console.log(url);" then copy/paste the returned string.

Comment: Then what is the "method" for displaying html within a javascript if statement in a webpage? @Scimonster it would help if you told me what is used as well as what isn't.

Comment: document has not a method called innerHTML. Use document.body.innerHTML()

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it slightly differently

Add both markup to the page, and show/hide as approproate:

```
<table id="table"><tr> hello </tr></table>
<span id="title"><b>This is my news page</b></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var url = document.location.pathname;
    if( url == '/tagged/photos' ){
        $('#title').hide();
        $('#table').show();
    }
    if( url == '/tagged/news' )
    {
        $('#title').show();
        $('#table').hide();
    }
})
</script>
```

*I have assumed you have `JQuery` since it is tagged*

Answer (score 0):

You're using `document.innerHTML`, which [doesn't exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document). At the very least, you need to get a proper element:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = 'some HTML';
```

Setting aside everything else that's wrong with this approach, I'm not sure, why would you use `document.write()` in one branch and `someElement.innerHTML` in the other.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```js
function pagePopulate() {
  // you're looking at the pathname, use a sensible (meaningful) variable-name:
  var pagePath = document.location.pathname,
    // this is a map, of the relationship between page and content:
    pathToContent = {
      // pagename : html
      'photos': '<table><tbody><tr><td>photos page</td></tr></tbody></table>',
      'news': '<b>This is the news page</b>'
    },
    // getting a reference to the <body> element:
    body = document.querySelector('body');

  // setting the innerHTML of the <body>,
  // if pagePath = 'tagged/photos', splitting with '/' would return:
  // ['tagged','photos'], calling 'pop()' returns the last element of the array
  // 'photos', which returns that string to the square brackets, resulting in:
  // pathToContent['photos'], which would yield the '<table>...</table>' HTML.
  // if that call resulted in an undefined, or falsey, value, then the default
  // (the string *after* the '||' would be used instead:
  body.innerHTML = pathToContent[pagePath.split('/').pop()] || '<h2>Something went wrong</h2><img src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" />';
}

// calling the function:
pagePopulate();
```

References:

- [`||` (logical 'or' operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).
- [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).